# I want to know CSS vs inline style

Tags: html, css, frontend

I understand that there are inline css, internal css, and external css in how to apply css. But I have a question. I heard that in the 1990s html was created and you used inline style on html to give the site style. And I know that css was born that can separate styles because I thought it was not good to write style code together in the html file. So are css and inline styles different? I know that there is an inline method within the way that css can be applied, but isn't the inline style a method that already existed before css was born? I'm panicking.

Can inline style be said to be a separate styling method from css?
Or has the inline style already existed before the css, but has it been reborn as a new inline css method that applies the css as an inline style since the birth of the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes "inline style" (at least in the manner you are using it) is different from "inline css".

When we talk of inline css, we mean styles applied via the "style" attribute.

Elements in early HTML did not have a style attribute. Styling was applied via a collection of dedicated attributes, such as "align", "bgcolor" & "topmargin", as well as dedicated styling elements like "center", "font" & "big".